# XmlParseException - The invocation of the constructor - The calling thread must be STA

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception

This is apparently a popular question, but I haven't found any solutions that relate closely to or fix my issue.

It's a C# WPF program with two projects - one for UI and one for the back end.

XmlParseException occurred: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'Sundial.UI.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '4' and line position '9'.

Checking out the InnerException, I'm getting "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this."

Here's that section from my MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="Sundial.UI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:Sundial.UI.Views"
        Title="Sundial"
        MinWidth="550" MinHeight="400"
        Width="1100" Height="700">
    <Grid>
        <Views:SundialControl/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The error is confusing to me because I haven't added anything new since the last successful run.  This popped up only after I began trying to change the names of the projects in my solution.  I'm also not writing a multithreaded program (at least as far as I know).

Comment: Pasting the full call stack from the exception would probably be very helpful in diagnosing this crash.

Comment: Thank, Bradley.  Where would I go to find the call stack?  I'm having trouble finding info about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things I figured out:

1) This isn't a GOOD answer, but the first thing I ended up doing was rebuilding the program from scratch by starting a new solution, creating the projects (with the new names we're using) and copying the relevant code back in.  It was a pain, but the new version works now.

2) As I was copying settings over from the original, I noticed the Assembly Name and Default Namespace in the properties window of the front-end project didn't match the project name.  On a hunch, I changed this to match, and the original now works again as well.  I skipped over these originally because I suspected changing them might change the name of the generated .exe file (which I wanted to keep).  The .exe name did have to change, unfortunately.

I never did find the call stack window in my version of Visual Studio, either.  It's listed most places as being under debug -> windows, but I've only got Breakpoints, Output, and Immediate shown there.

Comment: you can always do a <ctrl><alt> C when your program is in break mode to view call stack. you also will get the option to see it under debug --> windows if your program is running or in break mode.